# ORM Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, entity-framework, design-patterns

This is more of a question where I am looking for opinions.  I am working on a project that uses both NHibernate and EntityFramework (this is by design, wanted flexibility).  So, I went ahead and started working on a Repository pattern, but came across a slight dilemma.

Basically, I wanted to know what you guys think about the following areas:

1. Should the Repository be a singleton? - This will allow me to keep the sessions opened, but at the same time, I think it's going to keep connections opened to the database.  For NHibernate, the ORM can only gurantee an objet is the same within the same session.  This is ideal for easy coding, but there are definatly ways to overcome this using keys and overriding the GetHashCode and Equals methods.
2. If it's not a singleton (or even if it is), should I be closing the connections as soon as they are used?  For NHibernate, that means closing the session each time the Repository is "Disposed", which is after every use.
3. Have you implemented a Repository pattern for either NHibernate or EF 4.0 and found any useful ideas?

Comment: @John: There is no such thing as C#.NET. It's just called "C#".

Comment: Clearly this is on topic, I'm not sure who would be so disingenuous to vote it's not. @John Saunders you're nitpicking on words. You have C# the EMCA language specification, then you have C#.NET which the standard view of C# being compromised of all of the capabilities of .NET + the raw language itself.

Comment: @Chris: Most of the time when someone says "C#.NET", it's because they know about "VB.NET" and assume that the naming schemes are the same. They're not.

Comment: @Chris: I felt it should be moved to Programmer's, which is a better place for subjective discussion.

Comment: I meant it to be for people who want to look at the topic, to understand I'm targeting my functionality in a C# application on the .NET platform.  I too imply C# is .NET, but as Chris said... I just wanted it to be clear, C# or .NET people look @ this, as I can understand VB.NET examples also...

Comment: I guess the header "off topic" is in of itself disingenuous when it's in regards to SO vs Programmers if you don't click on it to see why it's shown as off topic.

Comment: Take a peek at this article: http://bit.ly/bF7jL3. It describes how to hide the O/RM behind a Unit of Work and Repository while still allowing to LINQ query over it. This might give you some directions.

Answer (score 4):

Don't code the creation of singletons yourself (ie the singleton pattern itself), use an IOC framework like StructureMap to handle the Lifecycle management of objects.

1. This we can't answer. If it's singleton it must be thread safe in regards to the resources it manages internally (like a connection pool of DB live connections). Threadsafe code isn't trivial.
2. This we can't answer. It depends on how you act with your model. It also depends whether you want people to be able to read through a DataReader which requires an active connection to the database. This also affects things like lazy loading which requires active sessions which becomes a nightmare with databinding.
3. Here's everything I've come up with in regards to creating a repository pattern for NH: [Creating a common generic and extensible NHiberate Repository version 2](http://dotnetchris.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/creating-a-common-generic-and-extensible-nhiberate-repository-version-2/)

Comment: Looking at your sample on your site, it appears your repository is deeply inetertwined with nhibernate.  Mine is a little more generic, offering only Save/Delete/ToQueryable.  As far as singletons and thread safty being hard, wouldn't that just be a matter of locking a static object before executing anything that can be non-thread safe?

Comment: Locking gets as complex as the resources you have to secure need to be from each other. I didn't specifically say it was hard, just nontrivial. Threading is never trivial. Keep in mind the point of locking too, it might real easy to make it thread safe by forcing single threaded access where every single consumer has to wait for the previous consumers requests to finish ;)  In regards to the notion of a "more generic" repository there's a discussion on that in my comments. I think it's pointless.

Comment: If I really had to create another layer of abstraction I would create a wrapper that wraps my repository usage. You can only abstract away so much before you get to nothingness. Or that you need to create an entire meta DSL for querying objects that you have to translate to real working code/sql at the deepest parts of your ORM. If you were serious about this, I would start with the DetatchedCriterion pattern and then build new criteria -> db code converters (or perhaps leverage NH's code directly for SQL atleast)

Answer (score 0):

First question, does it **have** to be NHibernate? Why not take a look at using EF4 with an IoC, my favorite is [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/), then you non longer have to worry about making your repository singleton as StructureMap gives options to keep the scope open by request, by HttpContext, by Hybrid. You of course have the option to use the Singleton pattern with your Repository I'm just not sold on it being a viable option in a case like this.

Hope that helps more than it confuses you.